# How can I use cordova-plugin-background mode

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, background-process

I need some assistance to make my App working in background.
I created my first App with Cordova 10, jquerymobile and it works fine excepted in backgound.

The idea is to installed the following plugin [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode), but I get some difficulties to understand how.

I installed the plugin and then I added the following

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById('deviceready').classList.add('deviseIsReady');
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    if(Pages.checkConnection() == true)
        {
            Maps.load(); 
            setInterval(Maps.load, 300000);   
        }
}
```

In that way, the mobile is ready, the background mode is actived. I upload my App to my Android but my App stop working.

I wonder, if this is would be a solution

```
$(window).load(function(){

    document.addEventListener("offline", Pages.offLine, false);
    document.getElementById("refresh").addEventListener("click", Maps.refresh);
    document.getElementById("ffield").addEventListener("change", Maps.field);
    document.getElementById("fstations").addEventListener("change", Charts.changeStation);
    document.getElementById("threshold").addEventListener("change", Pref.threshold);
    document.getElementById("ffieldpref").addEventListener("change", Pref.field);
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('EVENT', backgroundEvent);
    
});


function backgroundEvent(){
    if(cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive()){
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.moveToBackground();
    }
    else
    {
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();
    }
}
```

But I do not know when, it will be actived and if it will work with IOS devise.

Some of you have an experience with Cordova and how to setup the background mode with jQuery Mobile? Any examples?

Many thank for your help and suggestion.

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Refresh some data when the app resumes ?

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply. My app need to get the temperature from the database, and if a temperature is under the threshold, the phone must ring two or three time (vibrate would be nice as well). If the map or the values are not updated during the sleep mode, that's not important at least the value are refreshed as soon as the APP is reopned (or waked up). I also investigated on push notification without success. What is very important is to have a sound alarm. Then the owner open the APP and see the status

Comment: I think you would be better with a background fetch task instead, to do your pull from the database.. Check out https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use katzer's cordova-plugin-background-mode with Cordova 10. Works fine on 9.0, but that's as high as it goes. If your Builder program allows you a choice of Cordova versions, pick 9.  I have been unable to find an adequate substitute for the plugin that works in 10.

Also in Android, check your config.xml or AndroidManifest.xml and make sure there is FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission. This is absolutely required for background operation.

Comment: Adding the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission helped me prevent the app from getting killed as soon as it went in the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I had crash issues in my REACTJS->Cordova when it was enabled and I put the app in background mode. I corrected it by including this in my config.xml
[Config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyJz7.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34718799)